# Can $WD=I_2$ for these matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Can someone help?

---

> $W\in R^{2\times 3}$ with first row $\pmatrix {1&1&1}$
>
> $D\in R^{3\times 2}$ with first row $\pmatrix {2&2}$
>
> Can the above matrices exist so that $WD=I_2$ ?

---

my ideas...

$rankW$ is either $1$ or $2$

$rankD$ is either $1$ or $2$

$rankI_2=2$

$rankWD\le min(rankW,rankD) \implies rankWD\le2$

---

Help...

Comment: Basically, if we find two matrices, we will have solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea to check ranks first is good. Since by that check the existence of the matrices seems plausible, try to find the matrices.  There are a lot of degrees of freedom, so let's erase some of them and fashion arbitrarily a row-rank 2 matrix for $W$ and then use that to fill out $D$.  This isn't sketchy because we leave ourselves four variables in $D$, which will result in four equations in $4$ variables so long as $W$ has independent rows. 
So, let
$$ 
W =  
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now to fill out $D$ you can just write 
$$D = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and solve the resulting system of linear equations.  The system will be solvable!

Comment: Well, I was trying to solve this without putting 'convenient' numbers in matrix $A$. This really helped. Thank you very much @BadamBaplan

Answer (score 2):

For example, we can take
$$
W = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&2&0}, \quad
D = \pmatrix{2&2\\-1  &-1/2\\0&-3/2}
$$

Comment: $WD=I_2$ it's OK, thank you !!!